# Text and Polymorphism

Tags: haskell, polymorphism

I have the following piece of code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Data.List
import Data.Text hiding (foldl1', map)

gDatatoText :: Show a => [(a, a)] -> Text
gDatatoText xs = foldl1' append alltext
  where conv (a,b) = append (t' a) $ append "\t" (append (t' b) "\n")
        t' = numtoText
        alltext = map conv xs

numtoText :: Show a => a -> Text
numtoText = pack . show
```

Now this works fine for the following input:

```
λ> let a = [(1,2)] :: [(Int,Int)]
λ> gDatatoText a
"1\t2\n"
```

Now I want it for work for inputs like this:

```
λ> let b = [(1,2)] :: [(Int,Double)]
λ> gDatatoText b
```

Now this throws error like this:

```
Couldn't match type `Double' with `Int'
    Expected type: [(Int, Int)]
      Actual type: [(Int, Double)]
```

Now my gut feeling says that this can be solved by `RankNTypes`. But my attempts have failed. Any pointers on how to solve this ? Is this solvable using `RankNTypes` ?

Comment: well compare `gDatatoText :: Show a => [(a, a)] -> Text` with `let b = [(1,2)] :: [(Int,Double)]` and `gDatatoText b` ...

Comment: @CarstenKönig Both `Int` and `Double` are instance of `Show`.

Comment: but you cannot match `(a,a)` with `(Int, Double)` ;) ... maybe try `(Show a, Show b) => [(a, b)] -> Text` instead ...

Comment: @CarstenKönig Thanks, I get an idea why it is not working. :) It works if input is supplied with `[(Int,Int)]` or `[(Double,Double)]`, It doesn't work when different types are mixed. Is this solvable using some `RankNType` or some other technique ?

Comment: ... no you don't need fancy extensions ... David gave you the answer ... look below :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The binding `t'` restricts the type of `numtoText` (due to the monomorphism restriction), so we start by getting rid of it and just using `numtoText` directly.

```
conv (a,b) = append (numtoText a) $ append "\t" (append (numtoText b) "\n")
```

The other two options would be to give `t'` an explicit type signature `t' :: Show a -> Text` or to enable `NoMonomorphismRestriction`. I would opt for getting rid of `t'` altogether though.

Now, all we have to do is change your type signature for `gDatatoText`:

```
gDatatoText :: (Show a, Show b) => [(a, b)] -> Text
```

Your previous type signature required that both elements of the tuples have the same type, but that isn't necessary. All that is necessary is that both of those types have a `Show` instance.

**Regarding `RankNTypes`**

`RankNTypes` is completely unrelated to this issue. `RankNTypes` for when you need to nest a `forall` inside of another type (such as a function type), as in `(forall a. f a -> a) -> [Int] -> Int` which is an example of a rank-2 type. That type is different from `forall a. (f a -> a) -> [Int] -> Int`. In the former case, the *caller* of the function `(forall a. f a -> a)` gets to decide the type of `a`, in the latter case the function gets to pick the type. The first example requires `RankNTypes`, the second one does not (and is the same as just `(f a -> a) -> [Int] -> Int`. `forall`s at the top-level are implicit in Haskell).

The short of it is, `RankNTypes` is for `forall`s inside arguments passed to type constructors.